# Is there a way to edit "show values as" in excel's pivot table using openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I have pivot table with multiple dimensions and metric that should show calculation as
"% of parental Row Total".

I've tried to setup this manually in excel, open workbook in openpyxl and save again, but it seems like this only change number format to percentage and return "show values as "No Calculation".

Is there a way to edit "show values as" for specific metric in excel pivot table using openpyxl?